# SSIS Script Task Delete Files using a Wildcard

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

Using SQL Server 2014 \ VS 2019.  I have the below C# script task to delete files in a folder older than x number of days, and this works.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        int RetentionPeriod = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["$Package::FileRententionDays"].Value.ToString());
        string directoryPath = Dts.Variables["CSV_ArchivePath"].Value.ToString();
        string[] oldFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.*");

        foreach (string currFile in oldFiles)
        {
            FileInfo currFileInfo = new FileInfo(currFile);

            if (currFileInfo.LastWriteTime < (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-RetentionPeriod)))
            {
                currFileInfo.Delete();
            }
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

However, how do I modify to just say, delete all files in the directory where the filenames begins with 'ABC'?

Comment: Instead of inspecting the value of `currFileInfo.LastWriteTime` look at the value of `currFileInfo.FileName`

Comment: Change your file name wildcard to "ABC*.*" to return only files matching that pattern.

Comment: Either one of these fine comments would serve as an answer...

Comment: thank you all I will investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your start with "PREFIX" in a string something like `StartsWithPrefix`. Use the `String.StartsWith` Method to check if the `FileInfo` Name has the defined *prefix* needed to meet the requirements.

```
            int RetentionPeriod = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["$Package::FileRententionDays"].Value.ToString());
            string directoryPath = Dts.Variables["CSV_ArchivePath"].Value.ToString();
            string[] oldFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.*");

            string StartsWithPrefix = "ABC";

            foreach (string currFile in oldFiles)
            {
                FileInfo currFileInfo = new FileInfo(currFile);

                if (currFileInfo.LastWriteTime < (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-RetentionPeriod)) 
                    && currFileInfo.Name.StartsWith(StartsWithPrefix))
                {
                    currFileInfo.Delete();
                }
            }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netcore-3.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.name?view=netcore-3.1